# how to do a shallow copy with TypeScript in a type safe form

Tags: javascript, typescript, shallow-copy

```
const shallowCopy = <T>(obj: T): T => {
  const newObj: T = {}; // type error here (ts2322)
  const objKeys = Object.keys(obj) as (keyof T)[];

  for (const k of objKeys) {
    newObj[k] = obj[k];
  }

  return newObj;
}
```

line two has type problem:

> Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'T'.
> 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{}'.

how do i resolve it ?

[image]

Comment: which type of problem?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{}'.

Comment: `T` has no restrictions, an even if you specify it extends `Object`, most `T` would have required properties and `{}` would not be a valid assignment. Anything wrong with destructuring? `<T extends Object>(obj: T): T => ({...obj})` [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBAWBDANskB3AwiADgTxgF4YAeAFRgFMAPKSsAEwhgHkAjAK0uCgD4AKEJwBcMMgEpRFQrxj8A3gDplQjgF9xAbgCwAKD2hIsRERjyYiUQHIArFYA0MNqIDaARkcAmRwGYAumo6uobQTqYIKGhYuHj8iFp6BuAQIMiUimgA5vwAUgDKLAByitAATgCWYJnlAGaxiI5gAK6oXuLiSZCp6Vm5BcVlldV1-GyNLchtHcHJ3Rkg2SaEy04JukA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###### Method 1: `Object.assign()`

```
const shallowCopy = <T>(obj: T): T => {
  return Object.assign({}, obj);
}
```

###### Method 2: `as`

Use `as` to force TypeScript to interpret an object `as` the asserted type.

```
const shallowCopy = <T>(obj: T): T => {
  const newObj: Partial<T> = {};
  for (const k of Object.keys(obj)) {
    newObj[k] = obj[k];
  }
  return newObj as T;
}
```

Or

```
const shallowCopy = <T>(obj: T): T => {
  const newObj: T = {} as T;
  for (const k of Object.keys(obj)) {
    newObj[k] = obj[k];
  }
  return newObj;
}
```

###### Warning

The above uses `Object.keys()` hence will copy only `own` `enumerable` properties. [See](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys?retiredLocale=it)

Furthermore, if `T` is any instance different than `Object`, the `prototype` chain will be broken (but TS will not detect it). I suggest the usage of this function, which preserves the prototype chain.

```
const shallowCopy = <T>(obj: T): T => {
  const copy = Object.assign({}, obj);
  Object.setPrototypeOf(copy, Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));
  return copy;
}
```

###### Explanation

One of the main tasks TypeScript has is to make sure Objects are allways consistent to the declared type (something that is not imposed in JS). When you have something like this type

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  height?: number; 
}

let a: Person = {};
// (1)
a.name = 'Time';
// (2)
```

At point `(1)` the object `a` will be inconsistent with the type `Person` as it is missing the `name` property. At point `(2)` you made `a` consistent as now it has `name` property that is of type `String`. But still, TypeScript will complain as at point `(1)` even if there is no code you have a moment in time where `a` does not respect the definition.

The solution is to tell TS that `a` will be a `Partial<Person>` which means it contains part (or none) of the `Person` properties (not more and not different). Then once we are done with the assignment (and we are sure we assigned all mandatory properties) we (if required) force `a` to `Person` so that the following code can treat `a` simply as `Person` (and assume **as set** all the mandatory properties).

```
let a: Partial<Person> = {};
a.name = 'Time';
return a as Person;
```

In this example, if `T` is a POJO, at point `(1)`, `newObj` is compliant with type `T` (having received the assignment of all keys from a type `T` object). *Note that `T` may be an object with a `prototype` different than `Object` and hence `newObj` will not be compliant*. Even for POJOs, I have never seen any TS implementation (nor IDE) detect this pattern therefore we need to add the `as T`

```
const shallowCopy = <T>(obj: T): T => {
  const newObj: Partial<T> = {};
  for (const k of Object.keys(obj)) {
    newObj[k] = obj[k];
  }
  // (1)
  return newObj as T;
}
```

Comment: yeah, a compromise to tsc

Comment: Yes, more than a compromise, TS knows only part of the story, you need to tell him what you will be doing and what you did in some cases.

Comment: TypeScript's current static type declaration can't describe the process of dynamic assigning, and we had to use `as` for it or right?

Comment: @eczn I've added the explanation, hope it is clear

Answer (score 1):

```js
const shallowCopy = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>(obj: T) =>
    Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, elem) => ({
        ...acc,
        [elem]: acc[elem]
    }), {} as T)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBAWBDANskB3AwiADgTxgF4YAeAFRgFMAPKSsAEwhgCVLQAnBk6DgSzABzADQwArmADWYDGAB8cgBQgARgCsAXDDIBKLRUJyAUDFMwA8uvZQAdJMp4Iy9TpsdKDMcEqLFiYMCilMiUALY6RHIwigDeJmYJNkn%20gfEJpgDawWEAulopWSGhOWkwAL46ojFlMIjMukZAA)

You don't need to create new empty object and mutate him.

If you dont have any extra logic inside `reduce`, you probably should stick with `@crashmstr` 's solution

Answer (score -2):

You can create the object as `any` type and then cast it to the `T` type after copying all the keys:

```
const shallowCopy = <T>(obj: T): T => {
  const newObj: any = {};
  const objKeys = Object.keys(obj) as (keyof T)[];

  for (const k of objKeys) {
    newObj[k] = obj[k];
  }

  return newObj as T;
}
```

[POC](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=10&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBBAWBDANskB3AwiADgTxgF4YAeAFQD4AKEAIwCsAuGMgSmbKIpgG8AoGDFCRYYAKboA8g2aIwBYjwC%20AbgFDw0GHXoBpMXghEY0%20mOBQAdAGsDEGg1YxERqrbwgAZi1YBtALpq6p4gAE4wVMJa1treOvqGTvyCguJSDL7W-sY6mYHqSnzqoWJQAK6hYDBpps5GZGqFgkA)

Comment: use Any Type is bad practice in this case